# runtime error: w3cwebsocket is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am writing a Node.js app using ESM format, which uses [WebSocket-Node library](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node). But when I call w3cwebsocket's constructor, I got runtime error "w3cwebsocket is not a constructor". Below is how I reference it:

```
import * as wsPkg from 'websocket/index.js'
const ws = new wsPkg.w3cwebsocket(`${protocol}://${host}/ws`);
```

Compiling passes with no error. If I right click on "w3cwebsocet" and "go to definitions", VS code brings me to the correct constructor. What gives?

Also tried different forms of referencing it to no avail. For example

```
import * as pkg from 'websocket/index.js';
const w3cWS = pkg.w3cwebsocket;
const ws = new w3cWS(`${protocol}://${host}/ws`);
```